# Is there a python builtin to extract the 'set' of unhashable objects from a list, using 'is' comparison?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the set of all dictionaries in a list such that `dict1 is dict2 == False` for any two dictionaries in the set. A list of dictionaries cannot be reduced to a set by using `set()` since they are not hashable. I realize I can do the following:

```
dictlist = [.....]
setlist = []
for d in dictlist:
     if all(s is not d for s in setlist):
          setlist.append(d)
```

Is there a python built-in (using c, so much faster) analogous to set() for reducing lists, just without requiring hashable?

Comment: `is` != `==` and `is` != `in`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted to compare **identity** then store the result of the [`id()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) for each dictionary:

```
seen = set()
unique = [d for d in dictlist if id(d) not in seen and not seen.add(id(d))]
```

or

```
unique = {id(d): d for d in dictlist}.values()
```

This eliminates duplicates based on object identity, not on equality of the contents. The first form maintains order, the second does not (like a `set()` would).

For **equality**, the sequence of key-value pairs *is* hashable (if all values are hashable); a [`frozenset()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) of those would do as a key to test content uniqueness:

```
seen = set()
hashable = lambda d: frozenset(d.items())
unique = [d for d in dictlist if hashable(d) not in seen and not seen.add(hashable(d))]
```

for an order-preserving list or:

```
unique = {frozenset(d.items()): d for d in dictlist}.values()
```

if order is not important.

Comment: It *may* be OP confusing `is` and `==`, but if we assume OP knows what `is` means then they care about the dicts' identity, not their value (the key-value pairs). Edit: OP confirmed, so this answer does not apply, -1

Comment: Ran some tests using cProfile. Your id() solution is about 5-6 times faster than my method given in the question, which is very important to me. [If no one comes up with a python built-in, I will accept is as the answer.]

Comment: There is no built-in, this is not something that comes up all that often and it's easy enough to do with a short piece of code.

Comment: For Python 3, why not use a `frozenset` of key-value pairs?

Comment: Ran tests with your one-liner. Its infinitesimally faster than the first id() solution, but its a  pythonic one liner, so its infinitely better :)

Comment: @Jeff: the difference is in preserving order or not; preserving order takes more work. :-)

Comment: @user2357112: Good idea, and not limited to Python 3 either.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Once I was doing it, I tested your solution for ==. This time, my solution in the question using `if not d in setlist:` is about 12 times faster.

Comment: Use `timeit` to compare code snippets, to eliminate outside influences as much as possible. `cProfile` is only suitable to find bottlenecks in larger bodies of code, not for comparing two approaches to an algorithm.

Comment: Also, if you are comparing your algorithm (which uses nested loops) to my `frozenset()` variant, for smaller inputs the higher constant cost of creating the `frozenset()` *can* make the nested loop faster. Do make sure that you test with larger inputs.

Comment: Used a list of 100,000 , randomly filled with 3 different dictionaries. `dicts = ({'2':1}, {'3':4},{'a':3}` and `dictlist = [dicts[randint(0,2)] for p in range(0,100000)]`

Comment: @Jeff: which means your inner loop only has to cover at most 3 unique dictionaries, in the worst-case scenario. What happens if there are many more than 3 unique dictionaries?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Used 1000 different dicts this time, and... I lose *bigtime*;), at least with cProfile (though it has no noticeable impact on the id() one liner...).

Answer (score 0):

Since you care about the identity rather than the value, you want an identity set. There is no built-in identity set (or identity dict), partly because it's easy to build one yourself with reasonable performance:

```
dictlist = [.....]
iddict = {}
for d in dictlist:
     if id(d) not in iddict:
          iddict[id(d)] = d
```

The dicts you want are `iddict.values()`. It does not preserve the order of `dictlist`, but since you ask for a `set` analogue I assume this is no problem.